# How to inherit button type="action" odoo 15

Tags: inheritance, button, odoo-15

i'm trying to override a button which using type="action".

Original Button:

```
<button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
    type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}" data-hotkey="q"
    attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
```

I'm trying to inherit it with usual way which is use @name= .. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <record id="sale_order_view_form_create_contract_button" model="ir.ui.view" style="color:#e8bf6a;">>
        <field name="name">sale_order_view_form_create_contract_button</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="priority" eval="100"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't seem to work.

Please help, thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer:

It use name as usual:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

But in this view_order_form, odoo have defined 2 button which exactly the same as each other, so i've set index for it to make this work, such as i want to remove 2nd button, then i must add [2] to it, so it will look like this:

```
<!-- remove 2nd button "Create Invoice" in view_order_form -->
<xpath expr="//button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d'][2]" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Thanks you all for reading.